# WordPress: Как убрать sidebar для Страницы записей?

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте,
Вопрос заключается в следующем: Каким образом (без использования плагинов) я могу убрать sidebar со Страницы Записей?

Мои действия:
Есть страницы: Home, Blog, Contact

1. Копирую index.php - index-blog.php. В нем добавляю Template name:blog  index-blog.php и убираю get_sidebar();
2. Перехожу в админку, открываю Страницы - Blog - Изменить - Шаблон - применяю шаблон index-blog.php (Sidebar на странице Blog пропал)
3. Перехожу Настройки - Чтение. Выбираю Страницу Записей - Blog.
4. Перехожу на сайт - страница Blog - Sidebar отображается.

Если я правильно понимаю, то проблема кроется в иерархии файлов, но в чем именно ошибка, не могу понять. Очень прошу вашего совета

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте вывод сайдбара условным, для этого откройте редактор шаблона, выберите главную страницу (index.php) и оберните его в if.

Однако функции проверки на blog нету, поэтому необходим костыль. В самый низ файла пишете

```
function is_blog () {
global  $post;
$posttype = get_post_type($post );
return ( ((is_archive()) || (is_author()) || (is_category()) || (is_home()) || (is_single()) || (is_tag())) && ( $posttype == 'post')  ) ? true : false ;
```

}

Затем где у вас вывод сайдбара пишете так

```
<?php if (!is_blog()) {
get_sidebar();
} ?>
```

Таким образом сайдбар будет выведен на всех страницах кроме блога.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от темы. В общем случае достаточно удалить из [шаблона записи](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B8) вызов сайбара.

Но при любом изменения тем стоит использовать [механизм дочерних тем](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B).

Кроме того с версии 4.7 у ВП появилась возможность создавать шаблоны записей, аналогичные [шаблонам страниц](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B#.D0.A8.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86).